# why should .pbxproj file be treated as binary in version control systems?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, macos, cvs

In few places its been mentioned that .pbxproj file should be committed/imported as binary in cvs or git. it looks like script file in text format. what are reasons behind this suggestion that it should be treated as binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549578/6309), pbxproj is not really mergeable, being a complex property list managed as JSON.

The usual setting is in a `.gitattributes`:

```
*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge
```

As [explained here](http://shanesbrain.net/2008/7/9/using-xcode-with-git.html):

> This prevents Git from trying to fix newlines, show it in diffs, and excludes it from merges.

The other approach is:

```
*.pbxproj binary merge=union
```

As [documented her](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275082/6309)e, this didn't work well.

> The problem was that braces would become out of place on a regular basis, which made the files unreadable. It is true that tho does work most of the time - but fails maybe 1 out of 4 times.

Comment: On merge=union: http://haacked.com/archive/2014/04/16/csproj-merge-conflicts/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/36833404/6309

Comment: thanks VonC for answer and link..
what is the issue in just treating project files as binary without merge=union feature?

Comment: @nav1729 that should work too, as long as git does not try to merge it.

Comment: does this mean git merges files flagged as binary?

Comment: @nav1729 yes, it does mean binary for those files. Or binary-like (no diff, no merge)

Comment: Any issues with the first solution ?

Comment: @thibautnoah If by "first solution", you mean (3 years later) `*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge`, then the only issue is that those files are no longer merged. If you do modify them in one branch, you need to report said modification in the other branch.