# git recursive merge strategy options within .gitattributes

Tags: git, version-control

I'm struggling with forcing a specific merge strategy (`-s recursive -Xours`) for certain files within Git's `.gitattributes` file.

I have been playing with both .git/config and .gitattributes files with no success, what I managed so far does not take into account the `-X` option.

.gitattributes

```
*pom.xml merge=recursive
```

.git/config

```
[merge "recursive"]
  driver = true
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Use `git merge-file` in your merge driver.  Here, you can specify the options you want.  You're asking for `--ours`.  Be aware that this does not always work right.  You might even want `--union`, but be aware that this does not really work right either.  See [Can git be made to mostly auto-merge XML order-insensitive files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37849771/1256452) and [VS 2013 C# and Git: .csproj files don't merge upon pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36830144/1256452) for issues with trying to use either method with XML files.

#### Long

First, let's define the terms the way Git uses them:

- A *strategy* is the argument you pass to the `-s` flag to `git merge`: `git merge -s recursive`, `git merge -s resolve`, `git merge -s ours`, or `git merge -s octopus`.  (In practice you would never use the last one explicitly—instead, it's implied if you ask Git to merge multiple heads.)

  In other words, this is one of the names `ours`, `recursive`, or `resolve`.  In theory, you can write your own Git merge strategy as well, but that's very non-trivial (so much so that I have not heard of anyone doing it, though this might not mean that much).
- A *strategy option* the argument you pass to the `-X` flag, such as `-X ours` or `-X rename-threshold=<number>`.  I find this to be a bad name, as it's too easy to confuse with the *strategy*.  This is especially true when speaking: did you say "strategy" and then stop speaking but mean "strategy option" and you were just interrupted, or did you say "strategy" and stop speaking and actually mean "strategy"?  I like to call these *extended options*, which goes well with the `-X` flag, which then stands for "eXtended".)
- A *driver* is something you define in a `.gitattributes` file.  There are several flavors (filter, diff, and merge); here we're concerned with merge drivers.  Merge drivers are invoked *by* a strategy; the driver could, in theory, have access to at least *some* of the extended-options, but in practice they don't.  (Git should define `%`-expanders that provide them, and/or provide them in an environment variable; this would be relatively straightforward.)

With these definitions in mind, it's easy to see that this:

> I'm struggling with forcing a specific merge strategy (`-s recursive -Xours`) for certain files within Git's `.gitattributes` file.

is literally impossible.  That's true whether you mean *strategy* or *strategy option* here: both have been chosen long before we get to the *merge driver* defined in the `.gitattributes` file.

All is not necessarily lost, though!

You mention specifically `pom.xml`, for which you want a merge driver—the thing you can define in `.gitattributes`—that does a text style merge but takes "ours" if there is a conflict, a la the extended-option "ours".  What you have, instead, is a merge driver that will do an "ours" *strategy* merge: ignore both the merge base and their changes entirely, just taking "our" version of the file.

Compare your attempt with the answer at [Whats the Proper usage of .gitattributes with merge=ours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27134100/1256452): the only difference is the spelling of the driver name, where you use `recursive` instead of `ours`.  The name of the driver is not important, as long as it's not one of the known magic names (`text`, `binary`, and `union`): Git will run your driver instead of doing its own file-level merge, when it determines that there is a file-level merge to be performed.

[The gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) has this to say about defining a merge driver:

> The definition of a merge driver is done in the `.git/config` file, not in the `gitattributes` file, so strictly speaking this manual page is a wrong place to talk about it. However...
>
> To define a custom merge driver `filfre`, add a section to your `$GIT_DIR/config` file (or `$HOME/.gitconfig` file) like this:
>
> ```
> [merge "filfre"]
>     name = feel-free merge driver
>     driver = filfre %O %A %B %L %P
>     recursive = binary
> ```

(Side note: "recursive = binary" is not necessarily good advice, but let's press on here for now.)

> The `merge.*.name` variable gives the driver a human-readable name.
>
> The `merge.*.driver` variable’s value is used to construct a command to run to merge ancestor’s version (`%O`), current version (`%A`) and the other branches’ version (`%B`). These three tokens are replaced with the names of temporary files that hold the contents of these versions when the command line is built. Additionally, `%L` will be replaced with the conflict marker size (see below).

That is, `%O` names a temporary file containing the merge-base version of the file, while `%A` and `%B` name temporary files containing the `--ours` and `--theirs` versions of the file.  Your job, as filter-driver-writer, is to come up with a command that will perform the merge:

> The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the file named with `%A` by overwriting it, and exit with zero status if it managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.

Having performed the merge, you should *overwrite* the `%A`-named file with the result.  Since the `%A`-named file contains the `--ours` contents, a driver that does nothing, but then exits, declares that the correct contents for merging `%O` vs `%A` and `%B` is whatever is *already in `%A`*.

In other words, this is like the *ours strategy*.  It is not like the merge-favoring-ours-in-case-of-conflicts, resolve-or-recursive-with-`-Xours` strategy-plus-option.  But you don't want a whole *strategy* at all, as that deals with entire commits; you want a *single file* operation.  This is where `git merge-file` comes in.  Let's finish off the rest of the description now, though:

> The `merge.*.recursive` variable specifies what other merge driver to use when the merge driver is called for an internal merge between common ancestors, when there are more than one. When left unspecified, the driver itself is used for both internal merge and the final merge.

This is a bit confusing, but it applies *only to the recursive strategy*, and even then, only if `git merge-base --all HEAD <theirs>` prints out multiple hash IDs.  Most of the time, you don't need anything special here at all.  Using `recursive = binary` is equivalent to setting, for this one file, the strategy to `resolve`, because the `binary` internal merge driver just takes the `ours` version, which means that when `-s recursive` repeatedly merges merge bases, it just gets the first merge base version back each time.

Multiple merge bases are rare, and it's not always clear what to do with them, but omitting any setting will cause the internal recursive merges to use your merge driver, which is probably fine for most cases.  Your driver won't be *called* recursively; the recursion happens outside the calls to your driver.  If you view the recursion as a tree, your driver is, in effect, called as a post-order traversal.

> The merge driver can learn the pathname in which the merged result will be stored via placeholder `%P`.

More concretely, your driver will be called with `%A` expanding to, e.g., `.mergetmpA12345`, `%B` expanding to `.mergetmpB12345`, and `%O` expanding to `.mergetmpO12345`.  This is true regardless of whether you're being called to merge three copies of `README.txt`, three copies of `main.py`, or three copies of `pom.xml`: the temporary file names will be `.merge<something>`.

If you want, for whatever reason, to know that the "real name" of the file is `README.txt` or `main.py` or whatever, *that* is available in `%P`.  Don't *use* that file *now*—that's neither an input nor an output.  That's just the work-tree file's eventual name—it is, or will be, its (eventual) *name*, once the merge is all done.  For the moment, though, the name you should use—the one where you should deliver your merged file data—is whatever `%A` expands to (some `.merge<something>`).

#### Using `git merge-file`

[The `git merge-file` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html) tells us that the usage for `git merge-file` is:

> *git merge-file* [`-L <current-name>` [`-L <base-name>` [`-L <other-name>`]]]
>    [`--ours` | `--theirs` | `--union`] [`-p` | `--stdout`] [`-q` | `--quiet`] [`--marker-size=<n>`]
>    [`--`[`no-`]`diff3`] `<current-file> <base-file> <other-file>`

The three `-L` options are *labels* that `git merge-file` will place around conflicted sections.  The `--marker-size` option sets the size of the marker that `git merge-file` will place around conflicted sections.  The defaults are pretty similar to Git's own internal merge, so a lot of the time, these are not needed.  In your case, you're going to specify `--ours`, which means *there will never be unresolved conflicts* and therefore `-L` and `--marker-size` are not needed.

The `--ours` or `--theirs` or `--union` flag tells `git merge-file` how to handle conflicts.  Two of these flags are the same as the extended-options `-X ours` and `-X theirs`; you gain a third one that's not available in regular Git merge.

The `--diff3` or `--no-diff3` options again affect how conflicts are shown: they are equivalent to setting `merge.style` to `diff3` or to `merge` respectively.  Since you won't have conflicts, these are irrelevant.

Finally, you need to name three files: one containing the current ("ours") version data, one with the merge base version, and one with the other ("theirs") version.  When `git merge-file` finishes, it will rewrite the current-version file with the merged data.  Your `git merge` has, conveniently, built three such files, and uses them exactly this way, so you need only provide the `%A %O %B` options:

```
*pom.xml merge=favor-ours
```

and:

```
[merge "favor-ours"]
    name = merge driver that merges but favors ours a la -X ours
    driver = git merge-file --ours %A %O %B
```

Because of the `--ours` option, this merge will always succeed (`git merge-file` will exit 0), even if the result is not valid XML.